# How does Java parse an int from a long if long too big?

Tags: java, int, long-integer

How does java calculate this?

```
int number = (int) Long.parseLong("F9DFF755", 16);

Long.parseLong("F9DFF755", 16); == 4192204629 (too big to be stored by an int)
Casted to int : -102762667
```

How does java force a long to fit into an int?

Comment: It doesn't. The `int` just overflows.

Comment: it takes the right-most 32 bits, discarding the other 32 bits. This means that bit 32 from the original number (counting from the right) becomes the new sign bit.

Answer (score 8):

Casting a long to an int simply consist in keeping the last 32 bits of the long, and ignoring the first 32 bits.